# How could I launch "octomap_server>octomap_mapping.launch" with "openni_launch>openni.launch"?

Tags: openni, octomap, xtion, octomap-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**How could i do?**

---

**Update 1:**

***Hi my friend, i hava robot location in 2D mapping without any odometry. and i wanna 3d mapping with xtion.***

**i did it just for launch!**

```
mrl-x200@mrlx200-ThinkPad-X200:~$ roscd
mrl-x200@mrlx200-ThinkPad-X200:~/fuerte_workspace$ roscreate-pkg mapping_3d    std_msgs roscpp
mrl-x200@mrlx200-ThinkPad-X200:~/fuerte_workspace$ nautilus mapping_3dstd_msgs/
[/home/mrl-x200/fuerte_workspace/mapping_3dstd_msgs]
[right_click->    create new document->    empty document] && [name=do.launch]

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
    <include file="$(find openni_launch)/launch/openni.launch"/>
    <node pkg="octomap_server" type="octomap_server_node" name="octomap_server" output="screen">
        <param name="resolution" value="0.05" />       
        <param name="frame_id" type="string" value="camera_link" />
        <param name="base_frame_id" type="string" value="camera_link" />
        <param name="sensor_model/max_range" value="5.0" />
        <remap from="cloud_in" to="camera/depth/points" />
    </node>
</launch>

mrl-x200@mrlx200-ThinkPad-X200:~/fuerte_workspace$ roslaunch mapping_3d do.launch
mrl-x200@mrlx200-ThinkPad-X200:~/fuerte_workspace$ rosrun rviz rviz
```

**now I trying with hector_mapping**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
    <include file="$(find openni_launch)/launch/openni.launch"/>

    <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="camera_link" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 base_footprint camera_link 100" />

    <node pkg="octomap_server" type="octomap_server_node" name="octomap_server" output="screen">
        <param name="resolution" value="0.1" />     
        <param name="frame_id" type="string" value="map" />
        <param name="base_frame_id" type="string" value="base_footprint" />
        <param name="sensor_model/max_range" value="5.0" />
        <remap from="cloud_in" to="camera/depth/points" />
    </node> 
</launch>
```

**What is your opinion? :)**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/104721/how-could-i-launch-%22octomap_server%3Eoctomap_mapping.launch%22-with-%22openni_launch%3Eopenni.launch%22?/) by [Mohsen Hk](https://answers.ros.org/users/4097/mohsen-hk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2013-11-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't used hector_mapping myself, but from the documentation I understand it publishes a tf from map to odom. So I think you need to add another static transform publisher to define a transformation between base_footprint and odom. Does that help?

Best

Tim

---

Originally posted by [timster](https://answers.ros.org/users/3358/timster/) with karma: 396 on 2013-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mohsen Hk](https://answers.ros.org/users/4097/mohsen-hk/) on 2013-11-25**:
tnx, question updated.

**Comment by [timster](https://answers.ros.org/users/3358/timster/) on 2013-12-18**:
if my answer solved your question, please accept it as an answer (;